# Solr highlighting troubleshooting

Tags: solr, highlight

I'm using Solr 8.11.2 and I'm trying to highlight some words. My q is Fonte:Quotidiani and the query is correct but I haven't the highlight, I have ..em>Quotidiani</em.. in the result but I think a sould have something like "..em style="background-color: yellow">Quotidiani</em...".[image]

I'm Googling but I didn't someone how tried to highlight from User Interface of Solr.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: <em> is the default tag...You can replace it with whatsoever you want...Or you can pass it using hl.tag.pre & hl.tag.post. (hl.simple.pre for the Original Highlighter) Specifies the “tag” to use before a highlighted term. This can be any string, but is most often an HTML or XML tag.

Comment: You can also select a fragments builder with this parameter, or modify an existing implementation in solrconfig.xml

Comment: The idea is that you will style with CSS the `em` tag in your HTML page so that when you render the highlight value it will look highlighted. For example, adding something like this `<style>em { background-color: yellow}</style>` in your page will make the highlight text have a yellow background.

Comment: Hi Abhijit and Hector, I tried to change the file configuration and It is possible to change the tag em, I tried to change  hl.tag.pre/hl.tag.post too. Unfortunately the result is the same, there isn't the hightlight. Probably it isn't possible to do it in Solr UI. I used the tag <em style="background-color:yellow"></em> and it is correct in a razor page.

Comment: @maccarilab indeed, the highlighting tags are meant to be used in __your__ application. The Solr admin UI page does not highlight per-se.